# jQuery toggle with SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, toggle

I'm using a lot show/hide or toggle method with jQuery.

Now I'm struggling with SVG map.

So far I've tried like these examples:

```
    $(".runs-toggle").click(function(){
      $("#Snow_mashine").toggle();
    });


    $('.runs-toggle').click(function(){
        $("#Snow_mashine").toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

These two examples doesn't work.

.runs-toggle is a toggle button, so on first click, the #Snow_mashine (the object from the map) has to become hidden and after clicking again it will show #Snow_machine.

When I'm using like this:

```
$(".runs-toggle").click(function(){
  $("#Snow_mashine").hide();
});
```

It hides the element, but if I use .show() it doesn't shows the element.

I've read about instead of using .addClass(), the .attr() function is working with SVG, but I don't know how to achieve the toggle effect.

```
        $('.runs-toggle').click(function(){
           $("#Snow_mashine").attr("class","hidden");
        });
```

It's adding hidden class to the element and when that class has display:none with CSS, it works great, but how do I show the element after second click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$(".runs-toggle").click(function(){
    if($("#Snow_mashine").css("display")=="block")
    {
        $("#Snow_mashine").css("display", "none");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Snow_mashine").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: It's close, but the toggle works after second click. I mean when I click first it doesn't hides the element. After second click it does hides the element and on third click it shows the element back.

Comment: Could you please share your code sample in JSFiddle.

Comment: Ashish, unfortunately the map is custom made and I don't have permission to show it on JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes, now it works! I've set CSS to the object display:block and now the toggle works from the first click! Thank you very much! +1 from me!

Comment: Please can you explain me a bit this line of code? **("display")=="block")**

Comment: if($("#Snow_mashine").css("display")=="block") checks the value set in display property of the element with id 'Snow_mashine'. If it is block that means the element is showing in the page; then it calls the code $("#Snow_mashine").css("display", "none"); to set the display to none that hides the element. Then again when user clicks, it checks value set to display property again and this time it is set to 'none' so control goes to $("#Snow_mashine").css("display", "block"); which sets display value to block that shows the element again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue like this

```
$('.the-thing').attr('class') === 'the-thing hidden' ? $('.the-thing').attr('class', 'the-thing') : $('.the-thing').attr('class', 'the-thing hidden');
```

Answer (score -2):

To toggle a class you can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$('.runs-toggle').click(function(){
   $("#Snow_mashine").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: I've tried that too, it doesn't work with SVG object.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with the svg ?